# Change the alert text on add to cart action without selected variation in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, product

in Wordpress I'm using Woocommerce v3.3.5 and in single product pages for variable products, When I click the add to cart button while I don't select a variation option it popups an alert that says :

> Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.

and that is logical so far ..

My question is How to change the alert text to something else to fit my business?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WooCommerce has a filter "woocommerce_get_script_data" for all data sent to JavaScript including translated texts.
So this is the proper way to change this text :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'change_alert_text', 10, 2 );
function change_alert_text( $params, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' )
        $params['i18n_unavailable_text'] = __( 'Your new alert text', 'domain' );

    return $params;
}
```

If WooCommerce change this translation, you will have a problem with the accepted answer, your condition will be false.

Comment: This should be selected as accepted answer since it is more flexible and it would work regardless the WooCommerce language.
The above answer works only for English WC versions and there are no guarantees that they won't improve the message string in the near future, so the above snippet won't work any longer.

Answer (score 8):

For those who cannot get the code to work, it's because the variable called by Keylies code is using the wrong variable.

The correct variable follows the same coding conventions and is incredibly adaptable.

Either you can edit `public_html/YOURDOMAIN/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php`

Or drop the below code snippet (with relevant variables) into your themes `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'change_alert_text', 10, 2 );
function change_alert_text( $params, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' )
        $params['###INSERT YOUR VARIABLE HERE###'] = __( 'Your new alert text', 'domain' );
    return $params;
}
```

Replace `###INSERT YOUR VARIABLE HERE###` with any of the following (VARIABLE =>Default Message/Error/Text):

- 'i18n_no_matching_variations_text' => 'Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination.'
- 'i18n_make_a_selection_text' => 'Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.'
- 'i18n_unavailable_text' => 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.'

You can replicate the code to replace multiple shopwide errors by using:

Custom Error 1: `$params['i18n_make_a_selection_text'] = __( 'Hey, you... yeah you... make a selection!', 'domain' );`

Custom Error 2: `$params['i18n_unavailable_text'] = __( 'Oh no we've run out of that product but it's not the end of the world it'll be back soon', 'domain' );`

Comment: None of the other answered worked. only yours did. thank you for posting

Comment: can we change the title where there is a domain name or replace it with the logo image?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it should solve your problem:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customizing_variable_product_message', 97, 3 );
function customizing_variable_product_message( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
    if ($untranslated_text == 'Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.') {
        $translated_text = __( 'Here goes your custom text', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It's tested and works.

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec, I want to ask one question regarding this. What if we want to show a different alert for a different scenario like if the user doesn't select the size it should show the alert "Please select this size" and if the user doesn't select the color "please select the color " Can we do that? I am a bit new to WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Added to function.php this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'change_alert_text', 10, 2 );

function change_alert_text( $params, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' )
        $params['Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.'] = __( 'Your new alert text', 'sivona.ee' );
    return $params;
}
```

but still: https://prnt.sc/samecx

Comment: Please use code tags or backticks to format your function, too. That will vastly improve readability. Thanks!