# How to display error on attribute buttons if not selected as a red outline on them?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I am working on a woo-commerce theme. On the product page when user doesn't select any attribute and tries to add product to the cart, it shows error on the alert box like this

[image]

I want to make red outline on the options that are not selected as an error… How to do that?

Based on *[Change the alert text on add to cart action without selected variation in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216622/change-the-alert-text-on-add-to-cart-action-without-selected-variation-in-woocom/50220925#50220925)* answer thread, I have changed the message as client asked for it with the code below:

```
/* THIS CODE IS FOR CHANGING ALERT MESSAGE ON PRODUCT PAGE */
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customizing_variable_product_message', 97, 3 );
function customizing_variable_product_message( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
    if ($untranslated_text == 'Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.') {
        $translated_text = __( 'Please select all "Options" before adding product to the cart.', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Also I would like to replace domain name and the upper text with the websites logo.

Comment: Info: To change the domain name, simply replace `$domain` from the `$translated_text` by the slug of your desired domain name… Don't ask multiple questions at once: the rule is one question at the time, so split it. Also try to be more explicit to have more chances to get a useful answer.